# Ratio of rate of diffusion of two gases under constant temperature and pressure

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, erratum

I'm consulting one of higher classes books to study chemistry. I had been studying Graham's Law and question related to rate of diffusion. I came across a question<sup>[1]</sup> which says:

> Calculate the ratio of diffusion of $\ce{SO2}$ and $\ce{CO2}$ under constant temperature and pressure.

The question mentioned the mass of elements as following:   $\ce{S}=32$, $\ce{O}=16$, $\ce{C}=12$.

My solution of the question:

Molecular mass of $\ce{SO2}=32+32=64$

Molecular mass of $\ce{CO2}=12+32=44$

$$\frac{\textrm{Rate of diff. of}\ \ce{SO2}}{\textrm{Rate of diff. of}\  \ce{CO2}} = \sqrt{\frac{44}{64}} = \frac{\sqrt{11}}{4} $$

But the book has a different answer at the back, where it says $1:2$. I rechecked and performed all the maths again, but still cannot find this answer. Is the book incorrect, or have I made a mistake? If the latter, please help me find it.

1. D. N. Singh: *Basic Concepts of Inorganic Chemistry, 2nd Edition.*
   Pearson India, December 2011. ISBN: 9788131768617
   [URL of publisher](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/basic-concepts-of/9788131768617)

Comment: If you made a mistake, I'm making the same. To me, your solution looks fine!

Comment: I think you're right here as well...